# Lazarus cross compile from 32bit to 64bit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cross-compiling, lazarus

I know I can cross compile from 64bit to 32bit in Lazarus:
http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Cross_compiling#From_Linux_x64_to_Linux_i386

But I need to compile 64bit from a 32bit OS install. My CPU is 64bit but I never installed 64bit Ubuntu when I did my OS install.

I want to try to keep away from installing a virtualbox with 64bit Ubuntu as it's a lot of time required and my Lazarus is very customized. So I'm looking for some way to compile into 64bit from my 32bit Linux OS.

Answer (score -1):

According to http://wiki.freepascal.org/Cross_compiling#Host_and_target_on_different_CPUs it should be no problem!

Comment: Ok, I've read that and that's all well and good but there is zero documentation on cross compiling for architecture, hence why I posted here as I don't have the fogiest idea how to do it and what Linux Libraries I need also.